# CompletableFuture: whenCompleteAsync() does not let me re-throw an Exception

Tags: java, asynchronous, exception, completable-future

I am new to the world of CompletableFuture. I am trying to do some negative tests, in a way that will allow me to throw an exception intentionally. This exception will decide the PASS/FAIL.

Here's the code snippet:

```
    protected CompletableFuture<Response> executeAsync(@NonNull Supplier<Response> call) {
        return CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(call::get)
                .whenCompleteAsync((response, exception) -> {
                    if (exception == null) {
                        try {
                            Helper.throwIfNotExpected(clientProperties.getName(), response, null);
                        } catch (ServiceException e) {
                            throw new ServiceException(null,e.getMessage(),null);
                        }
                    } else {
                        log.error("Async API call failed.", exception);
                    }
                });
    }
```

This gives me an error saying **unhandled exception** in catch part. I looked up examples and documentation but could not find much information about Exception handling in supplyAsync/whenCompleteAsync. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried throwing an unchecked exception?

Comment: Have you tried catching the checked exceptions that Helper.throwIfNotExpected is declared as throwing?   If it's "throws Exception" then you need to "catch Exception" (or Throwable, but I'd suggest not going wider than you need).

Comment: Helper.throwIfNotExpected() "throws ServiceException".

Comment: Throwing unchecked exception gives me same error.

Comment: Side note: when you have a `Supplier` and call a method expecting a `Supplier`, just pass the `Supplier`, i.e. use `supplyAsync(call)` instead of `supplyAsync(call::get)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to work around the shortcoming of `CompletableFuture` regarding checked exceptions is to delegate to another `CompletableFuture` instance. For your example it would look like something along the lines of

```
protected CompletableFuture<Response> executeAsync(Supplier<Response> call) {
    CompletableFuture<Response> delegate = new CompletableFuture<>();

    CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(call)
        .whenCompleteAsync((response, exception) -> {
            if (exception == null) {
                try {
                    Helper.throwIfNotExpected(clientProperties.getName(), response, null);
                    delegate.complete(response);
                } catch (ServiceException e) {
                    delegate.completeExceptionally(new ServiceException(null,e.getMessage(),null));
                }
            } else {
                log.error("Async API call failed.", exception);
                delegate.completeExceptionally(exception);
            }
        });

    return delegate;
}
```